# Errors including app.component.ts in the TypeScript compilation context

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have set up an Angular2 project following the Angular2 docs
when I want to import the `Component` from `@angular/core` typescript gives me this error

> The file "C:/sendbox/mean/client/app/app.component.ts" is not included
>   in the TypeScript compilation context.  If this is not intended,
>   please check the "files" or "filesGlob" section of your tsconfig.json
>   file.at line 1 col 1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your `tsconfig.json` is not in the `app`. Accoring to http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

> Using tsconfig.json
>
> ```
> By invoking tsc with no input files, in which case the compiler searches for the tsconfig.json file starting in the current directory
> ```
>
> and continuing up the parent directory chain.
>       By invoking tsc with no input files and a --project (or just -p) command line option that specifies the path of a directory containing
>   a tsconfig.json file, or a path to a valid .json file containing the
>   configurations.